# Derive an explicit formula for the following recurrence for $n\geq 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

$a_n = n/2 *a_{n-1}$ is my recurrence

with $a_0 = 1$

What do they mean by an explicit formula and what are the step I should be taking to solve this.

What I have tried so far:

Write out the first 8 terms and try to find a pattern but I didn't really know if this is what I should be doing??

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Finding an explicit formula means that we need to find a function $f(n)$ such that $a_n=f(n)$. This equation is referred to as the explicit formula. I show in this answer one way to find the explicit form.

Take logarithms on both sides,

$$\ln a_n=\ln (\frac{n}{2})+\ln a_{n-1}$$

$$\ln a_n-\ln a_{n-1}=\ln \frac{1}{2}+\ln n$$

Summing both sides from $n=1$ to $k$ gives,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{k} (\ln a_n-\ln a_{n-1})=\sum_{n=1}^{k} (\ln \frac{1}{2}+\ln n)$$

Notice the left hand side is a telescoping sum. Also notice that:

$$\ln 1+\ln 2+\cdots \ln k=\ln (1 \cdot 2 \cdot \cdots k)=\ln k!$$

This gives,

$$\ln a_k-\ln a_0=k\ln (\frac{1}{2})+\ln k!$$

Substitute $a_0=1$.

$$\ln a_k=k\ln (\frac{1}{2})+\ln k!$$

$$a_k=e^{k\ln (\frac{1}{2})+\ln k!}$$

$$a_k=k!\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k$$

Or if you prefer,

$$a_n=n!\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
a_n &= \frac n 2a_{n-1}\\
&= \frac n 2\cdot\frac {n-1} 2a_{n-2}\\
&= \frac n 2\cdot\frac {n-1} 2\cdot\frac {n-2} 2a_{n-3}\\
&\!\!\!\quad\vdots\\
&=\frac n 2\cdot\frac {n-1} 2\cdot\frac {n-2} 2\cdots\frac 12a_0\\
&= \boxed{\frac{n!}{2^n}}
\end{align}